# Integrating Activiti with JSF

Tags: jsf, activiti, bpmn

Am trying to start activiti engine from jsf

```
@ManagedBean(name = "activitiProcess")
@ViewScoped
public class ActivitiProcess implements Serializable {

    private String  filename    = "D:/WORKSPACE/activiti1/src/main/resources/diagrams/MyProcess.bpmn";

    public ActivitiProcess() {

    }

    public void startProcess() {

        System.out.println("hello world");
        try {

            ProcessEngine engine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine(); //returns null


            RepositoryService repositoryService = engine.getRepositoryService();
            repositoryService.createDeployment().addInputStream("myProcess.bpmn20.xml", new FileInputStream(filename)).deploy();
            RuntimeService runtimeService = engine.getRuntimeService();

            ProcessDefinition definition = engine.getRepositoryService().createProcessDefinitionQuery().processDefinitionKey("myProcess").singleResult();

            FormService formService = engine.getFormService();
            // List<FormProperty> formList = formService.getStartFormData(definition.getId()).getFormProperties();

            Map<String, String> formProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
            /* use the jsf variable instead */
            formProperties.put("filePath", "D://somePath");
            formService.submitStartFormData(definition.getId(), formProperties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

the engine always returns as null , I read that the activiti.cfg.xml file should be in the class path , I've put the file under  web-inf/classes  but still , engine returns null which means activiti can't initialize the engine , any ideas ?

Comment: does it need any db properties file?

Comment: not a must , but even though , am using the same configuration in a standalone activiti application and it's working fine
you might check 
http://forums.activiti.org/content/using-activiti-without-spring

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
@Inject
 private ProcessEngine engine;
```

if you want to run a CDI Bean inside a container, you are not allowed to use the new keyword. Instead, you need to inject the bean and the container does the
rest, meaning, the container is the one responsible for managing the life cycle of the bean: it creates the instance; it gets rid of it. So how do you  initialize a bean if you can’t call a constructor? Well, the container gives you a handle after constructing an instance and before destroying it.